# What voltage should the i5 6600K be set to?

Tags: cpu, overclocking, intel-core-i5

I recently purchased the Core i5 6600K and an ASUS Maximus VIII Gene motherboard. After setting up the automatic overclocking, it was brought to my attention that a CPU voltage of 1.425v is way too high, and could cause degredation very quickly. I was told that it should be 1.2v. So I tried it, but Windows kept bluescreening. Same with 1.25v. In the BIOS, the "Auto" setting puts it at 1.425v.

After looking around at other people with the same combo, I found 3 people using a manual setting of 1.35v. So I changed it to that, and everything seems stable so far. The CPU is designed for 3.5 GHz, but I currently have it at 4.6 GHz.

Is 1.35v the appropriate CPU voltage, especially considering I'm doing some light overclocking? And why would it have been automatically set to 1.425v?

PS - I'm a beginner in this subject.

Current status:

[image]

Comment: There is no single corrrect value. All CPUs have some variation.  Best we can give you is a 'for most CPU's of this model, set voltage in this range for this clockspeed'.

Comment: The max operating voltage for the 6th generation CPU's is 1.52v. You can find that information in the [6th Generation Intel® Core™ Processor Family Datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/desktop-6th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.html). It states this in section 7.2, page 113.

Comment: Here is some good indication of overclock results with their voltage: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wQwYMGsSnMpKxrEesNVUSoP7hGykFWw1ygJsxwx64e8/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Alex Thanks, that shows 1.36v for the same CPU/MB.

Comment: Well every CPU is different but if you have the same settings and it's stable, why not?! :)